# Tkinter Radiobutton spawns frames

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to this GUI business with python2.7 and Tkinter. I'm trying to create a new frame depending on which Radiobutton the user choose, like a menu. When I click on a radiobutton it creats a new frame just like I want, but if I continue to click on the same radiobutton, it will create another frame, and another frame, etc. Can't seem to figure out on how to check if the Radiobutton is already marked (clicked on just once).

Hope I made myself clear, thankful for help!

```
class Books:
    """ Books() is the main class for creating the whole interface """
    def __init__(self):
    """ Initialize the first function in class Books() """

        self.library = "library.txt"
        self.filepath = os.getcwd() + "/" + self.library

        self.window = Tk()

        self.window.title("Personal library")
        self.window.wm_iconbitmap(default="myicon.ico")

        userChoice = Frame(self.window, height = 1, bd = 1, relief = RIDGE)
        userChoice.pack(side = TOP, pady = 10, padx = 5)

        self.menuChoice = IntVar()

        btAddBooks = Radiobutton(userChoice, text = "Add a new book to the library", value = 1, variable = self.menuChoice, command = self.processChoice)
        btAddBooks.grid(row = 1, sticky = W)

        btFindBooks = Radiobutton(userChoice, text = "Print info about a book", value = 2, variable = self.menuChoice, command = self.processChoice)
        btFindBooks.grid(row = 2, sticky = W)

        btPrintBooks = Radiobutton(userChoice, text = "Print all book titles in library", value = 3, variable = self.menuChoice, command = self.processChoice)
        btPrintBooks.grid(row = 3, sticky = W


    def processChoice(self):
        """ Used to handle user choice of Radiobuttons """
        if self.menuChoice.get() == 1:
            self.processAddBooks()
        elif self.menuChoice.get() == 2:
            self.processFindBook()
        elif self.menuChoice.get() == 3:
            self.processShowBooks(self.filepath)


    def processAddBooks(self):
        """ Add a new book to the library. """
        # Create a new frame
        questions = Frame(self.window, height = 1, bd = 1, relief = SUNKEN)
        questions.pack(fill = X, pady = 10, padx = 5)

        # Do stuff with frame here...
```

Comment: radiobuttons aren't really designed for this sort of use. They are designed to make choices, not to perform actions. I suspect your users will be surprised when they make a choice and a window pops up.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Just wanted to make the program 'smooth'. I'll skip it and implement a 'Submit' button instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you only need one frame to be open at a time, you can call `frame.destroy()` on the previous frame before you instantiate the new frame. However, this approach will require that there be something initialized for Tkinter to `destroy` the first time one of the buttons is selected, otherwise you'll get an error. For my purpose, I just created a throwaway class with a `destroy` method that did nothing, then used an instance of that class as a placeholder bound to that variable until my Toplevel widget was created for the first time. If you want multiple frames open at the same time, just not duplicates of the same option, try using a different variable name for each frame and only creating the frame `if not frame.winfo_exists()`--though I'm not 100% sure this wouldn't be susceptible to the same issue of needing a placeholder assigned to that variable until the frame is created the first time. If such is needed, the placeholder class would need a `winfo_exists()` method that would `return False`.